# 「Xの原始として,Y」の意味 (What does the phrase Xの原始としてのY　mean?)

Tags: grammar, academic-japanese

## Japanese

最近、日本人と共同研究しています。私の方は哲学の専門家。共同研究者は発表を作っていて、その発表の中に以下の表現を使いました：

> 「Xの原始としてのY」

日本語の母国語ではない私に、これは「YはXの原始」という意味をしていると思いました。それが当ていませんか。言い換えて、意味として、これはYはXの原始かXはYの原始か。またはその二つ以外の意味がありますか。

## English

Recently, I've been engaged in some collaborative research with several Japanese researchers. I'm a philosopher by trade. One of our collaborators made a presentation which included the phrase:

> Xの原始としてのY

As a non-native speaker, I thought this means that Y is X's origin or principle. Is that correct? Rewording it, is this saying that X is Y's principle or Y is X's principle? Or does it mean something different from either of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「Xの原始{げんし}としてのY」

この表現について、先ず確認しておきたいのは、

> 原始 = Y
>
> 原始 ≠ X

という点です。日本語学習者の間で、助詞「の」の**前後に来る言葉**の関係性に関する誤解が多く見受けられますので、今一度ご確認ください。実際に「意味として、これはYはXの原始かXはYの原始か」と問われていることもあり、この点に言及した次第です。

「原形」、「源」、「根源」という意味で「原始」を使用することは学術的にはあるようなので、市井の会話においての「原始」の使われ方は、今回は余り気にされなくても良いかと思います。

意味としては、単純に、

> XはYから始まっている
>
> Xの起源/原形はYである

という理解で良いでしょう。センテンス風の解釈になってしまいましたが、言うまでもなく「Xの​原始​としてのY」は名詞句です。

Answer (score 0):

ありません、YはXの元となるという意味だけです

> 「Xの原始としてのY」 = Y as the primitive of X

また「原始として」という表現はあまり一般的ではないと思います

学術用語なら別ですが、通常、原始人、原始時代、原始的なという用法で使われます

- Xの根本としてのY
- Xの祖先としてのY
- Xの祖語としてのY
- Xの基本としてのY

対象によって異なりますが、しっくりくる言葉があるはずです